# order by price and sort order number opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

How can I order products by price ascending, and sort order number at same time.

I tried

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order, ASC p.price DSC";
```

But it orders only by sort order number

for example if I have:

```
product_id | price | sort_order
1          | 20    | 0
2          | 10    | 0
3          | 30    | 1
4          | 40    | 0
```

I want to get

```
product_id | price | sort_order
2          | 10    | 0
1          | 20    | 0
4          | 40    | 0
3          | 30    | 1
```

Comment: Would that be because of the syntax error - `ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC, p.price DESC`? or maybe your code path isn't run? `ORDER BY` without `LIMIT` is ignored in subqueries.

Comment: This query would not execute at all, so something doesn't add up here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are having wrong syntax, try changing to below, it will sort by `sort_order` first and then the `price` :

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC, p.price ASC";
```

Comment: @user3514052 I've edited the answer, please try again?

Comment: I can not believe it was just a syntax error. Shame on me.